# How to set the marker visible on google map draggable direcion

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a Directions on google map , and there is my code.
In the code , there are four Markers on it. 
I want that I can decide which markers I want to hide.
How to set the marker visible on google map draggable direcion?

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 22.65, lng: 120.30}  
  });

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
  });

  directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });

  displayRoute('22.650927, 120.328185' , '22.656672, 120.307596', directionsService,
      directionsDisplay);
}

function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {

  service.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    waypoints: [{location:new google.maps.LatLng(22.651682, 120.324307)},{location:new google.maps.LatLng(22.655168, 120.320009)}], 
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    avoidTolls: true
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      display.setDirections(response);

    } else {
      alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
    }
  });

}
```

[The picture shows the directions look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y34l9.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, try getting the markers like this:

`var markers = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get','markers');`

Comment: Also assuming OP is using a specific plugin. There is no evidence of that in code shown